# How to update/refresh datatable after an ajax update or insert call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have this table right here that is populated by query results from my database:

```
<div class="card-block">
    <table id="catTbl" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cat-update">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Title</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <?php
                 include "../processes/getLists.php";
                 $process = new getLists();
                 $process->getCatForTbl();
                 //used PHP PDO for that
             ?>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <p id="message" style="margin-top: 15px"></p>
</div>
```

I can properly update and insert rows in the database using ajax so the page won't load every after process but the problem is if I don't reload my page after every insert/update the datatable won't update with the newly updated/inserted rows.

I tried `$("#catTbl").ajax.reload()`, `$("#catTbl").clear().draw()` but they won't work unless my table is somehow made up of `json`. Is there anything I can do for my table to reload every after ajax call? **Add: I don't want the whole page to reload, just the datatable on submit event.**

```
$('#updateCatForm').on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"../ajax/updateCat.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#updateCatForm').serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            $('#updateCatForm')[0].reset();
            $('#cat-update').modal('hide');
            $('#message').html(data);
            //I put the table reload solutions here and nothing seemed to work :<
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `document.location.reload()` in a callback?

Comment: Thank you, I just used that and it works but it refreshes the page, I want to refresh only the table not the whole page though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Make sure the selector is same. Or you can simply store in a variable and use it like this

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

Then after ajax

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

---Edit----

```
table.ajax.reload({
    "ajax": {
           "url": '${ctx}/work/list_ajax.json',
           "type": 'POST',
           "data":{ 
              data:$('form').serialize()
           }
    } 
});
```

I'm not entirely sure about this, I didn't give it a try but it's something along this line to get the data and display on the table. I'm sorry I couldn't provide you with a working snippet. Remeber the returned data should be in a proper format or it won't work.

Comment: Not working, as stated above I already tried `table.ajax.reload()`. It gives me an alert:
_DataTables warning: table id=catTbl - Invalid JSON response._

Comment: So, refresh url should give back some json response.

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow up on this. Been a bit busy. So here you are getting the data for table manually. Instead, try the dataTable ajax to get the data you want. That way you won't even have to manually call reload, it should call it for you.